# how to insure that after inactivity of 15 min in userpage will goes for logout with a popup message in salesforce?

Tags: salesforce1-app, session

Can anyone tell me to  ensure that after 15 minutes of inactivity our customer portal logs out the user and prompts them to log back in after inactivity?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

In you session settings for the organization select the options as shown.

1)Set Force logout to true

2)Select Disable session timeout warning popup to false

Note that this will apply to all the users and profiles .Not only to portal users .